# Live chart using jqPlot: Performance issue

Tags: jquery, charts, live, jqplot

For a project I need to implement a live update chart using jqPlot.

Please see the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fracu/HrZcj/242/
(for the sake of simplicity the values are generated randomly)

I successfully managed to do the job, but I'm having performance issues: After some minutes with the chart running the browser starts getting slow till the moment when I close the chart's tab. (tested with Firefox and Chrome)

I can't see where the problem is, since I'm not doing anything special, just replotting the chart every n seconds with an array where the chart values are stored.

Another issue I'm having is that when I resize the x axis the "ticks" are positioned on the left of the chart and they are not distributed equally along the axis.

Could you please give me a clue on what could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Javascript:

```
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [new Array(1)], {
        series: [{yaxis:'y2axis',showMarker:true,fill:false,neighborThreshold:3,rendererOptions:{smooth:true}}],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{formatString:'%H:%M:%S'}},
            y2axis:{tickOptions:{formatString:'%.2f'}}
        },
    });

    var myData = [], x, y, samples = 0, secsBuffer = 60, refreshInterval = 1, sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;

    $("#refreshInterval").change(function () {
        clearInterval(cInt);
        cInt = window.setInterval(updateSeries, $("#refreshInterval").val() * 1000);
        refreshInterval = $("#refreshInterval").val();
        sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;
    });

    $("#secsBuffer").change(function () {
        secsBuffer = $("#secsBuffer").val();
        sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;
    });

    function updateSeries() {
        if (samples > sampleWindow) {
            var diff = samples - sampleWindow;
            myData.splice(0, diff);
            samples -= diff;
        }
        x = (new Date()).getTime();
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        myData.push([x, y]);

        plot1.resetAxesScale();
        plot1.axes.xaxis.numberTicks = 15;
        plot1.axes.y2axis.numberTicks = 15;
        plot1.axes.xaxis.min = x - (secsBuffer * 1000);
        plot1.axes.xaxis.max = x;
        plot1.series[0].data = myData;
        plot1.replot();
        samples++;
    }
    cInt = window.setInterval(updateSeries, refreshInterval * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that plotting involves some processing and more data means more processing, which is why it slows down the browser after some time.

What i can suggest you is to start shifting from the beginning of your data array after the plot has reached a certain time range.

```
if(time limit has reached) myData.shift();
```

It may not be the best solution. But you'll still be able to view the data for last 10 minutes (or whatever time period you decided to start trimming the array) on the plot without crashing the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer GayashanNA. I'm already doing something like you suggest in my code. But instead of myData.shift() im using myData.splice(0,diff) where diff is the data in the array that has exceeded the sample window.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my mistake, i didn't see that.